# Query error while subtracting 2 database tables

Tags: java, mysql

good solution and subtraction and could achieve the query is using this but I have a question as to forbid me subtracting negative numbers eg 4-6 = -2 what I would like to make is that just me reste until it reaches 0 and I reset the counter block until that method I can achieve apologize if you use the same question this is my query to use to achieve the subtraction

```
UPDATE Equipo c SET c.horasmotor= (CAST(c.horasmotor AS INT) -" + historial.getHorasTrabajadas() + ") WHERE c.id=" + expediente.getId()
```

Comment: What if you would start to use sentences?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your query like this :

```
update Equipo
   JOIN  Historial on
    Equipo.id=Historial.id
 set Equipo.horasmotor=(Equipo.horasmotor - Historial.horasTrabajadas)
```

Try this:

```
   Update Equipo 
   JOIN  Historial 
   where Historial.id=1 
   set Equipo.horasmotor= (CAST(Equipo.horasmotor AS INT) -  CAST(Historial.horasTrabajadas AS INT))
```

Comment: The SET identifier is missing from the UPDATE clause.
The equal sign must be specified.
A path expression must start with an identification variable.
 The expression is invalid, which means it does not follow the JPQL grammar.
The query contains a malformed ending.
The state field cannot be resolved.  this error execute query

Comment: this error show me execute query  
The SET identifier is missing from the UPDATE clause. The equal sign must be specified. A path expression must start with an identification variable. The expression is invalid, which means it does not follow the JPQL grammar. The query contains a malformed ending. The state field cannot be resolved

Comment: im create this query and work SELECT CAST(c.horasmotor AS INT) - CAST(d.horasTrabajadas AS INT) FROM Equipo c JOIN Historial d WHERE c.id=1 how to pass it at update

Comment: @alexander like above

Comment: post the query @alexander

Comment: this query Update Equipo e JOIN  Historial c set e.horasmotor= (CAST(e.horasmotor AS INT) - CAST(c.horasTrabajadas AS INT)) WHERE c.id=1

Comment: this error sa me sql execute your query [16, 16] The SET identifier is missing from the UPDATE clause.
[33, 33] The equal sign must be specified.
[16, 32]  The expression is invalid, which means it does not follow the JPQL grammar.
[34, 37] The identification variable 'set' cannot be a reserved word.

Comment: finally try now @alexander